# Modify npm Package in Angular 8

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I have an angular 8 Application that i've been serving on my localhost to build it, in this App i'm using an NPM package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rb-fab-speed-dial) that i modified slightly (I just changed the mat-fab into a mat-mini-fab and 2 property of css) and it was working great. Now that it's getting to a finnish i'm testing it on a server so i made a build of my Application by using

> ng build --prod

It doesn't use my modified code anymore since it reinstall the original version at build.

I would have asked to the collaborator of this repo for a change but it was last published 2 years ago and i don't think he would help me now.
If it was only for the css, the "!important" attribute do the job just right, but i need to modify the mat-fab into a mat-mini-fab in the template.

Of course i can modify the built bundled js but it's just not practical.

I would like to know if there's a way to modify it only locally, or, if needed, how to fork the package to make the modifications appear in the built application since there is no github that host the original files?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: could you not write a post build script to replace the original files with your updated file?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm taking a look at post build script !

Comment: actually just realized that would be a pain. better to do post install i.e. after `npm install`, as post build it would all be compiled.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it copying the modificated file to the package folder on postinstall script:

    `"postinstall": "cp myFile.js node_modules/package/path/"`

Comment: @VictorOliveira Thanks for your answer but i'm not sure i understand, your modified file would be copied to the node_modules ? Even if there is no node_modules anymore after the build ? 
Or maybe the postInstall happen before the bundler?

Comment: @AnthonyD Yes, I replaced the original file in node_modules folder with my modified file. It works because happens before the bundler even without node_modules folder. I know that it isn't the best way but solved my problem.

Comment: @VictorOliveira I'm going to give it a try, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I did not manage to do it with the postinstall script neither because in fact there was 2 js files that had same name, which code was different for the es5 and the es 2015, so instead i finnaly modified everything with CSS with the !important attribute, like this i managed to change the size of the mat-fab into a mat-mini-fab size and makke the correct adjustements. Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to do it with the postinstall and the postbuild script neither because in fact there was 2 js files that had same name, which code was different for the es5 and the es 2015, so instead i modified everything with CSS thanks to the !important attribute, like this i managed to change the size of the mat-fab into a mat-mini-fab size and make the correct adjustements. Thanks for your help ! :)